# defaultLocale is not keeping default lang in Next.js i18n

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, react-intl

I'm trying to make my default language in Next.js i18n but always is getting "En" as default language called like fallback.

And I also get this error:

> Error: [@formatjs/intl Error MISSING_DATA] Missing locale data for locale: "sq" in Intl.NumberFormat. Using default locale: "en" as fallback

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['sq', 'en'],
        defaultLocale: "sq",
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you provide the sq language json ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Next.js will [automatically detect](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#automatic-locale-detection) which locale the user prefers based on the `Accept-Language` header sent in the page request.

In your case, although your default locale is `sq`, the `en` locale is detected in the `Accept-Language` header so you get redirected to the locale-prefixed path.

This behaviour can be disabled by setting `localeDetection` to `false` in your i18n options.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['sq', 'en'],
        defaultLocale: 'sq',
        localeDetection: false
    }
}
```

From the [Disabling Automatic Locale Detection](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#disabling-automatic-locale-detection) documentation:

> When `localeDetection` is set to `false` Next.js will no longer
> automatically redirect based on the user's preferred locale and will
> only provide locale information detected from either the locale based
> domain or locale path as described above.

---

As a side note, regarding the `@formatjs/intl` error, it indicates that you're using an environment/browser that doesn't have support for the `sq` locale. You may want to look into [`@formatjs/intl-numberformat`](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat) to polyfill that locale data.

Comment: For the formatjs/intl i found this code but didn't work :                                                   
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/polyfill-force’ // Using force to use our polyfill
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/kk’ // Add locales you want
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/ru’ // Add locales you want
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/add-all-tz' // Add ALL tz data

Comment: Did you literally copy that? You'll want to add the locale you need: `sq`.

Comment: Yeah i added /sq but same result again, should i put this piece of code in file: _app.js or?

Comment: My code:                                                                                                               
 import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/polyfill-force' // Using force to use our polyfill
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/sq' // Add locales you want
import '@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/add-all-tz' // Add ALL tz data

Comment: I just realised I might have linked the wrong polyfill. Try [`@formatjs/intl-numberformat`](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat), as the error is with `Intl.NumberFormat`. Updated my answer.