# Server Next js automatically redirect to english despite browser has another language

Tags: internationalization, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

Server Next.js automatically redirect to english despite browser has another language
http://localhost:3000/en instead http://localhost:3000.

My `next-i18next.config`

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['ua', 'en', 'ru', 'ar'],
        defaultLocale: 'ua',
    }
}
```

Ukrainian and English are installed in the browser. Ukrainian in the beginning.

`Accept-Language` in request headers: `uk,en;q=0.9`

How to make it not redirected to English? What am I doing wrong?
My package.json

```
{
    "name": "connect-prerelease",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start -p $PORT"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@parse/react-ssr": "0.0.1-alpha.14",
        "@types/parse": "^2.18.6",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "next": "10.2.3",
        "next-i18next": "^8.5.0",
        "next-images": "^1.8.1",
        "parse": "^3.2.0",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "17.0.11",
        "next-compose": "0.0.2",
        "typescript": "4.3.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Need 'ua' -> 'uk'

Comment: Does this answer your question: [defaultLocale is not keeping default lang in Next.js i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730980/defaultlocale-is-not-keeping-default-lang-in-next-js-i18n)? The `Accept-Language` value is making Next.js redirect to the `en` locale.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in `next.config.js`:

```json
i18n: {
    localeDetection: false 
}
```

Reference: [i18n object](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The default language does not display the prefix, you need to set `locale: false`, and need to accurately match the prefix `/en`.

```js
{
  source: '/en',
  destination: `/blog/one`,
  permanent: true,
  locale: false,
}
```

For other languages use `/` matching.

```js
{
  source: '/',
  destination: `/blog/one`,
  permanent: true,
}
```

Need to pay attention to the order of the array.

Combine them together.

```js
async redirects() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/en',
      destination: `/blog/one`,
      permanent: true,
      locale: false,
    },
    {
      source: '/',
      destination: `/blog/one`,
      permanent: true,
    },
  ];
},
```

**Next Redirects**

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects