# next-i18next switching to default locale after refresh

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

Hello I have a problem with next-i18next in NextJS. When I switch to `cs` locale and refresh the page the page switch locale back to `en`. I have Chrome default language set to English though. But shouldnt it works just fine when I want to browse the page in Czech language?

I'm adding codesandbox to replicate the issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-glitter-o3xsjl?file=/pages/_app.tsx

I was following the offical guide from next-i18next with this example which is working fine

https://next.i18next.com/

https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next

Comment: Does it work with a link component?

Comment: <Link
            href='/'
            locale={router.locale === 'en' ? 'de' : 'en'}
          >
            <button>
              {t('change-locale', { changeTo: router.locale === 'en' ? 'de' : 'en' })}
            </button>
          </Link>

Comment: Unfortunately it still has same behaviour with next/link

Comment: Tried your example and it seems to behave correctly.
If your Accept-Language header contains en somewhere and not cs, it will show english... like described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#automatic-locale-detection

Comment: Next.js automatically detects which locale to use based on the `Accept-Language` header. You can disable this by setting `localeDetection` to `false` in your config file. See [defaultLocale is not keeping default lang in Next.js i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730980/defaultlocale-is-not-keeping-default-lang-in-next-js-i18n).