# How to use Nextjs internationalization with a default lang?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, lang

It's two days I'm reading the [Nextjs internationalization doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization)

I want to use two langs: `en`, `fa`. I can switch between them as well, and the URLs would look like this:

```
https://example.com/en
https://example.com/fa
```

All I want to do is, defining the `en` one as default, so the **expected result** is:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/fa
```

Any idea how can I do that? I couldn't find anything related to that in the doc.

---

Here is the code I have:

/src/app/[lang]/page.js

```
// 'use client'
import { getDictionary } from './dictionaries'
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";

// const router = useRouter();
export default async function Page({ params: { lang } }) {
    const dict = await getDictionary(lang) // en
    return (
        <>
            <button>{dict.products.cart}</button>
       </>
    ) // Add to Cart
}`
```

/src/app/[lang]/dictionaries.js

```
import 'server-only'

const dictionaries = {
    en: () => import('../dictionaries/en.json').then((module) => module.default),
    fa: () => import('../dictionaries/fa.json').then((module) => module.default),
}

export const getDictionary = async (locale) => dictionaries[locale]()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [NextJS documentation on internationalization routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#locale-strategies) it seems like you can just define the default locale in `next.config.js` to set a default language:

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fa'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730980/defaultlocale-is-not-keeping-default-lang-in-next-js-i18n) also has a lot of information that could be useful for you.

Sample project structure:

```
project-root/
|-- src/
    |-- app/
    |-- ...
|-- ...
|-- middleware.js
|-- next.config.js
|- ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still doesn't work. I guess I'm using the middleware wrongly,  Should be [this file](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization#routing-overview) in which path? under `/src/middleware.js` or `/src/app/middleware.js`?

Comment: Neither, it should be in the root directory (same as `next.config.js`). I've edited my answer to show a sample project structure.